# hardhat verify contract faild! Help!

Tags: contract-development, etherscan, hardhat

I use command `npx hardhat verify`, and the log is:

```
Nothing to compile
No need to generate any newer typings.
Successfully submitted source code for contract
contracts/ygu/yguToken.sol:YGUToken at 0x2707207f7ebfA8166406dC5e389fD9e19607617E
for verification on the block explorer. Waiting for verification result...

We tried verifying your contract YGUToken without including any unrelated one, but it failed.
Trying again with the full solc input used to compile and deploy it.
This means that unrelated contracts may be displayed on Etherscan...

Successfully submitted source code for contract
contracts/ygu/yguToken.sol:YGUToken at 0x2707207f7ebfA8166406dC5e389fD9e19607617E
for verification on the block explorer. Waiting for verification result...

Error in plugin @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan: The contract verification failed.
Reason: Fail - Unable to verify

NomicLabsHardhatPluginError: The contract verification failed.
Reason: Fail - Unable to verify
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.verifySubtask [as action] (/Users/lbc/github/llbec/solidity-box/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan/src/index.ts:332:9)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Environment._runTaskDefinition (/Users/lbc/github/llbec/solidity-box/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:219:14)
    at async Environment.run (/Users/lbc/github/llbec/solidity-box/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:131:14)
    at async Environment._runTaskDefinition (/Users/lbc/github/llbec/solidity-box/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:219:14)
    at async Environment.run (/Users/lbc/github/llbec/solidity-box/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:131:14)
    at async main (/Users/lbc/github/llbec/solidity-box/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/cli/cli.ts:218:5)
```

Comment: See [multisol](https://github.com/paulrberg/multisol).

Comment: I had some trouble with verifying my contracts but then I concerned the following StackOverflow issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70146047/verify-publish-smart-contract-on-etherscan-rinkeby